# How to update element html with jQuery .load

Tags: jquery

i have made this script to keep a chat div updated.

```
    <script>
 $(document).ready(function() {
     $("#contenedor").load("chatquery.php");
   var refreshId = setInterval(function() { }, 9000);
   $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
});
</script>
```

But the page **chatquery.php**, is not being displayed in the div, **#contenedor**, can you tell me what was my mistake in the script?.

can i do this?

```
<script>
 $(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajaxSetup({
        cache: false
    });
    var refreshId = setInterval(function () {
        $("#contenedor").load("chatquery.php**?id=<?php echo $_GET['id'];?>**");
    }, 9000);
});
</script>
```

Comment: No markup returned === error in PHP script or wrong path/filename

Comment: What is the point of the empty `setInterval` call? Have you checked the console for errors?

Answer (score 1):

If no response is returned, then there is something wrong on your server side(php code) and try doing it  using `setTimeout`:

```
function loadDiv(){
   $("#contenedor").load("chatquery.php");
}

$(document).ready(function () {
 $.ajaxSetup({
    cache: false
 });
   loadDiv();
   setTimeout( loadDiv, 9000);
});
```